Pandas convert_dtypes(infer_objects=Fals, convert_string=True) converting numeric data into string only for 1st occurrence of numeric column
I'm trying to load data from oracle DB table into pandas dataframe in a string format where my table has many NUMBER fields having data without decimal places.
ex. tableA (col1 varchar2(30), col2 number, col3, varchar2(12).... col8 number, col9 number)
loading this tableA data into pandas dataframe by following code and then trying to convert everything into string data type -
import connectorx as cx
import pandas as pd

sql_qry= "select col1,col2,...col9 from tableA"

df = cx.read_sql(<oracle conn. string>, sql_qry, return_type = 'pandas')

df = df.convert_ctypes(infer_objects=False, convert_string=True)

df.to_csv(<csv file object>, header=True, sep='|',index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf8',quotechar='"')

Now in csv file for col2 values are coming as whole integer without decimal point but all other numeric column's values are coming with decimal point whereas in database those are having only whole integer values.
so output looks like this -
"col1","col2","col3",........."col8","col9"
"John","12532","A56"................"210008.0","315.0"
"Sam","16435","B5F",............"384.0","315.0"
"Vipin","67453","BG4",..........."4558.0","4675.0"

only col2 values are coming without decimal part and even though col8 and col9 in DB has whole integer values without decimal part but in csv those are coming with decimal part.
Any way to get those numeric values as is from the DB?
Tried following -
import connectorx as cx
import pandas as pd

sql_qry= "select col1,col2,...col9 from tableA"

df = cx.read_sql(<oracle conn. string>, sql_qry, return_type = 'pandas')

df = df.convert_ctypes(infer_objects=False, convert_string=True)

df.to_csv(<csv file object>, header=True, sep='|',index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf8',quotechar='"')

Now in csv file for col2 values are coming as whole integer without decimal point but all other numeric column's values are coming with decimal point whereas in database those are having only whole integer values.
so output looks like this -
"col1","col2","col3",........."col8","col9"
"John","12532","A56"................"210008.0","315.0"
"Sam","16435","B5F",............"384.0","315.0"
"Vipin","67453","BG4",..........."4558.0","4675.0"

Expected is  following -

"col1","col2","col3",........."col8","col9"
"John","12532","A56"................"210008","315"
"Sam","16435","B5F",............"384","315"
"Vipin","67453","BG4",..........."4558","4675"


how is this not a duplicate of your other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79006430/how-to-get-numeric-values-from-oracle-db-table-as-is-into-pandas-data-frame ?
