How to get numeric values from Oracle DB table as is into pandas data frame
Trying to load numeric column values from an existing oracle DB table into pandas data frame but all the numeric values are taking decimal part while exporting the columns into csv file except the 1st numeric column.
Ex. tabA is an oracle table having column (col1 varchar2(30), col2 number, col3 varchar2(10)....col8 number, col9 number) where values lok like
col1  col2   col3...........col8  col9
I1   23451   Sam  ..........2330   5
I2   33467   Jhon...........6672    8
I3   55562   Pamela ........ 2100    8

1st loading the data into pandas dataframe from oracle by connectorx.read_sql() and then writing the data frame into .csv file using pandas.to_csv method and in csv getting following data -
col1  col2   col3...........col8     col9
I1   23451   Sam  ..........2330.0    5.0
I2   33467   Jhon...........6672.0    8.0
I3   55562   Pamela ........ 2100.0    8.0

where as in DB table numeric values are whole integer without decimal part.
Expectation is csv should looks like following -
col1  col2   col3...........col8  col9
I1   23451   Sam  ..........2330   5
I2   33467   Jhon...........6672    8
I3   55562   Pamela ........ 2100    8

I tried to convert the dataframe's all columns into string datatype after loading data from oracle
using pandas.conver_dtypes(infer_objects=False,convert_string=True) but didn't work.
Tried to define schema of the dataframe as all columns as string before loading data from oracle but that also didn't work. Here is my sudo code -
import pandas as pd
import connectorx as cx

sql="select * from tabA"

df = cx.read_sql(<oracle conn. string>, sql, return_type ='pandas')
df = df.conver_dtypes(infer_objects=False,convert_string=True)
df.to_csv(<file_object>, header=True, sep='|',encoding='utf8', mode ='a',quotechar='"', quoting=1)

Is there any way to get the numeric values as is from the database without decimal part from Python end?
Trying to avoid the solution of converting numeric columns into sql query as string by using
oracle to_char() function like select to_char(col2), ...to_char(col8)  from tabA.
Any solution from Python end would be much helpful.

That maybe because the Dataframe columns are float type when it is created from the DB data. converting it into string won't remove the decimal.
What you might want to do is fix it like below with to_csv(float_format="%.0f")
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_records({"a":{"c":2, "d":3, "b":1}, "e":{"b":4, "c":5, "d":6.0}})

df.to_csv()
Out[29]: ',a,e\nc,2,5.0\nd,3,6.0\nb,1,4.0\n'

df.to_csv(float_format="%.0f")
',a,e\nc,2,5\nd,3,6\nb,1,4\n'


Thanks @vamsi_s for the solution. It's working for these numeric columns but for a column where it is real float value exists, there it would create problem by discarding decimal part right? How to handle that scenario?

Then maybe use something like applymap or map on those columns and convert them to int lambda x: str(int(x)) if x else x

can you describe the oracle table please.

and sample input with expected dataframe results, tks
